# Angularjs don't post hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I make `$http.post` call, but my hidden fields are not posted with the form.

Code:

```
         <sf:form ng-submit="post(form)" id="respond" >
          <input type="hidden"name="form.replyTo"  ng-model="replyTo" ng-value="1">
          <input type="hidden"  name="form.id" ng-model="id" ng-value="33" >

              <input class="diskafield" type="text" ng-model="form.name" >

              <input class="diskafield" type="text" ng-model="form.email" >

              <textarea class="diskafield" name="comments" ng-model="form.body"  required=""></textarea>

              <input class="diskabtn" type="button" ng-click="post(form)" value="Post Comment">
          </div>
      </sf:form>
```

and my controller is :

```
      app.controller('AddCommentController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.name="";
    $scope.email="";
    $scope.body="";
    $scope.id = "";
    $scope.replyTo = '';
    $scope.post= function(form) {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/add', form).success(function(response){
        }).error(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: all form input fields will be submitted, that's how forms work, just ignore the value you don't want...

Comment: I think his English is just bad, and is actually looking for why it does not post.

Comment: Just swap `name="form.replyTo"  ng-model="replyTo"`

Comment: hidden fields relying on ng-model need to have an ng-value of that variable. i.e. `...ng-model="form.id" ng-value="form.id"...`

Comment: If you send the model (`form`) then what's the point of having a hidden `input`?

Answer (score 4):

your posting `form` object so, if you need to attach the hidden properties to that `form` object,

```
<input type="hidden"name="form.replyTo"  ng-model="form.replyTo" ng-value="1">
<input type="hidden"  name="form.id" ng-model="form.id" ng-value="33" >
```

you need to change the model to `form.replyTo` and `form.id` like above.

and seems like you have miss use the `ng-model` and `name`,

for ex:

you mention `$scope.name`

and you use it in the form as a element name.

that's not the way to use it there is no relation between scope variables and input names here.

that should related to `ng-model`.

so clean example should be like.

```
$scope.form = {
    name : "",
    email : "",
    body : "",
    id : 33,
    replyTo : 1
};

$scope.post= function(form) {
    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/add', form).success(function(response){
    }).error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
}


<sf:form ng-submit="post(form)" id="respond" >
      <input type="hidden"name="form.replyTo"  ng-model="form.replyTo">
      <input type="hidden"  name="form.id" ng-model="form.id" >

          <input class="diskafield" type="text" ng-model="form.name" >

          <input class="diskafield" type="text" ng-model="form.email" >

          <textarea class="diskafield" name="comments" ng-model="form.body"  required=""></textarea>

          <input class="diskabtn" type="button" ng-click="post(form)" value="Post Comment">
      </div>
  </sf:form>
```

*actually you can remove the two hidden fields since that hidden field data is exists in the `$scope.form` object.*

here is a working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hnlFHbXbXt2vjUBQYlk?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like he just mixed up "name" and "ng-model".

Comment: @K.Toress i change to ng-model="form.replyTo" but not work yet.

Comment: @K.Toress i paste your code but not work again. why post other input but not hidden input?

Comment: please check the demo provided. :)